# PetaPoco is mapping 0 for every Id in my object?

Tags: sql-server-2014, petapoco

I have the following object:

```
public class VehicleMake
{
    [Column(Name = "MakeID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To get a list of vehicle makes, I am doing the following:

```
var vehicleMakes = _db.Fetch<VehicleMake>(@"SELECT DISTINCT(m.MakeID) AS Id, m.Name
                                            FROM vehicles v
                                            INNER JOIN makes m on m.MakeID = v.Make
                                            WHERE [Year] = @year
                                            ORDER BY m.Name", new { year });
```

When I run the `SQL in SSMS`, it returns the correct data, but in `VS, it is mapping 0 for every Id property`.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, I got it, in case anyone else runs into the problem.  Since I am doing:

`SELECT DISTINCT(m.MakeID) as Id...`, there is no reason to have:

`[Column(Name = "MakeID")]` since I am aliasing the column as `Id` already.